# Add an additional label control to an <ItemTemplate> dynamically in certain cases

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, datagrid, placeholder

How can I add an extra label control dynamically (should be added only on certain conditions). 
I am trying to do something like this:

```
 <asp:DataGrid id="dg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="Column1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton Runat="server" text="Column1 Hdr" ID="col1Hdr">
         </asp:LinkButton>
        </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="col1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Method1(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column1").ToString(), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column2").ToString())  %>' >           
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col2Holder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> 
       </asp:Label> 
      </ItemTemplate>     
   </asp:TemplateColumn> 
 </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Alternatively, I tried putting the placeholder in a seperate template:

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col2Holder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> 
  </EditItemTemplate>
```

but to no avail.
Any tips on  how I can create the Placeholder only in some cases (like for some values of Column1/Column2), rather than opt for a repeater approach...
I get a null reference exception but that was solved when I had to explicitly mention:

```
protected PlaceHolder col2Holder = new Placeholder();
```

instead of

```
protected PlaceHolder col2Holder;
```

But though method1 is able to set the 'Column1's text value correctly, it does nothing for the Column2's value...
Is there something I'm missing or is there a different way to do this?

Here's method1's defn:

```
public string Method1(string col1, string col2)
{
    col1 += "Called method1"; 
     Label col2label= new Label();

     col2label.Visible = true;
     col2label.Text = col2;         

     col2Holder.Controls.Add(col2label);
     col2Holder.DataBind();

return col1;
```

}

Comment: I would strongly recommend NOT to use DataBinder.Eval - its slow and evil. Better to cast to the correct type and get the data directly. What to cast to of course depends on your DataSource but lets say its a IEnumerable of DataRows, then you should write ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["Column1"] instead of DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column1")

Comment: the reason why you cant declare a variable named col2Holder on the Class Level and expect it to contain a reference to the placeholder inside your ItemTemplate is that there will be N number of ItemTemplates each containing their unique placeholder.

Comment: so what is a good way to fix this? I do need the <span> to be generated only in certain cases, not always. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where and when do you need the extra control to be inserted?

You should most likely hookup a method to the `OnItemDataBound` event and in there decide whether to add a control or not. The event gives you a reference to the item being bound so you can say `e.Item.Controls.Add(your_control)`

**Update**

Ah, now i get it what you're asking for. You need to add another argument to your `Method1` that takes a `DataGridItem`. When you call Method1 you add it like this `Method1(Container)` where `Container` refers to the `DataGridItem` in question. Then you can say in the `Method1`

```
public string Method1(DataGridItem item)
{
    string col1 = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "Column1").ToString();
    string col2 = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "Column2").ToString();

    var col2label = new Label() { Visible = true, Text = col2 };
    var col2Holder = item.FindControl("col2Holder");

    col2Holder.Controls.Add(col2label);

    return col1 + "Called method1";
}
```

Btw, you can't add any controls to a Label, your ItemTemplate should look like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="col1Label" runat="server" Text="<%# Method1(Container) %>" />
   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col2Holder" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you want the new Label to be nested inside the first label, you should do that explicit in the method, and leave out the placeholder:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="<%# Method1(Container) %>" />
</ItemTemplate>

public string Method1(DataGridItem item)
{
    string col1 = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "Column1").ToString();
    string col2 = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "Column2").ToString();

    var label = item.FindControl("label");
    var col2label = new Label() { Visible = true, Text = col2 };

    col1Holder.Controls.Add(col2label);

    return col1 + "Called method1";
}
```

Comment: I want the extra control to be inserted inside the <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="col1Label"> element, can be a div or a span. Should be inserted by checking not only values of Column1 = "something" but also values of Column2 != null.... as an example... i.e passing in both the values from database and adding the new control if valid values..

Comment: updated my answer with an exampe of how you can pass a reference to the ItemTemplate into your method so you can add new controls to it.

Comment: when you say Item you mean the <ItemTemplate> correct? Thinking how this method could be called now.. using an Id or something?

Comment: technically the item can be both ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate, FooterTemplate etc... its all of the same type and if you need to know what it is you can ask for Container.ItemType. If you want to have access to the DataItem inside your Method1 you can get it like item.DataItem and a id could be DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "id").

Comment: updated again, and moved the data retrieval code into the Method1 method to make it more clear how to interact with the DataGridItem. You just call the method like Method1(Container)

Comment: thanks so much for your help! unfortunately, I'm not now getting this error: 'TableRow' cannot have children of type 'PlaceHolder'. it's occuring where I nested the <asp:PlaceHolder> inside the <asp:Label> inside the <ItemTemplate> Help!

Comment: oh, why didnt i see that :) yes, you cant add children to a label. Updated my answer to point that out.

Comment: but I tried a simple control where I was able to successfully add a label control inside another label (not inside an <ItemTemplate>), using the placeholder (set to a label on certain events), i.e. nest two span tags on certain cases. It worked fine and the html got generated as expected. Wonder if it fails because of the ItemTemplate not allowing to put a placeholder?

Comment: you might be able to insert child controls, but then it has to be done explicit in code, since the asp.net compiler needs controls than contains nested markup to imlement the ITemplate interface, and Label doesn't. meaning, that new Label().Controls.Add(...) will work, <asp:Label runat="server> <asp:placeholder runat="server" /> </asp:label> won't.

Comment: do I need to do some kind of data binding, either to the outside label or the datagridItem itself? Thank you!

Comment: you need to set a datasource on your datagrid and call databind on it, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: Finally, I used a literal control for this, instead of the label control. It worked fine with the literal control, where I updated the text with whatever I needed to put into the placeholder. Thanks much for the tips!